# Jquery markup parsing - result from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I receive jQuery accordion panel markup from AJAX request. It contains `<h3>` and `<div>`, one after another.

However, I get some empty text node between them. How to get rid of this? I do not have space between those two tags in markup:

```
success: function (panel) {
  var $modifiedH3 = $(panel).eq(0); //allright, it's H3
  var $modifiedDiv = $(panel).eq(2); //it should be eq(1), but eq(1) is empty #text node...
}
```

Markup of panel is normal:

```
<h3>Header</h3><div>Content</div>
```

Comment: `eq` doesn't consider text nodes

Comment: Then why $(panel).eq(1) returns me this: `#text ""`?